# Run-Time Error (Send Mail from Spreadsheet)

Tags: excel, automation, sendmail

I have used Rob De Bruin's 'send range as mail' code to send out daily reports to the relevant people. After using this code for a few months it has broke and gives me a run-time error. Specifically during the cleanup 'cws.delete'.

I cant seem to debug and solve (code below):

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_Attachment_1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim Cws As Worksheet
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim Rnum As Long
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Integer
    Dim mailAddress As String
    Dim NewWB As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long


    On Error GoTo cleanup

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set Ash = Sheets("Sheet3")

    'Set filter range and filter column (column with names)
    Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:P" & Ash.Rows.Count)
    FieldNum = 10    'Filter column = A because the filter range start in column A

    'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
    Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
    FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
            CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

    'Count of the unique values + the header cell
    Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

    'If there are unique values start the loop
    If Rcount >= 2 Then
        For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

            'Look for the mail address in the MailInfo worksheet
            mailAddress = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                VLookup(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value, _
                          Worksheets("Mailinfo").Range("A1:B" & _
                                Worksheets("Mailinfo").Rows.Count), 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0


            If mailAddress <> "" Then

                'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
                FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                       Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

                'Copy the visible data in a new workbook
                With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End With

                Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

                rng.Copy
                With NewWB.Sheets(1)
                    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                    .Cells(1).Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

                'Create a file name
                TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
                TempFileName = "Daily Debit Balances" _
                             & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2016
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If

                'Save, Mail, Close and Delete the file
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                With NewWB
                    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName _
                          & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                    On Error Resume Next

                    Call AddAzureLabel(OutMail, "Restricted - Internal")
                    With OutMail
                        .To = mailAddress
                        .Subject = "Daily Balances Report"
                        .Attachments.Add NewWB.FullName
                        .Body = "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find attached your daily balances." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Kind regards," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Sam"
                        .Display  'Or use Send
                    End With
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    .Close savechanges:=False
                End With

                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
            End If

            'Close AutoFilter
            Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

        Next Rnum
    End If

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Cws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
```

Any help on this? CWS.Delete is where I get stuck using F8 also. Everything was working fine up until this point.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? Try to qualify the reference fully and then retest the code i.e. instead of `Set Cws = Worksheets.Add` use `Set Cws = WorkbookRef.Worksheets.Add` where WorkbookRef shall be your correct Workbook object reference.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried the above using workbooks("book4").worksheet etc. The error is still at cws.delete and is a run-time error '91' object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Error 91 means that the variable is getting dropped somewhere although I cannot see that being done in the code posted.

Comment: anything else i can try - i have no idea